# Tailwind background-opacity

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to apply a background opacity to a div using tailwinds, I have attempted to do it within the classes, using no custom settings within `tailwind.js`

```html
<div class="expanded fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50 w-full h-full flex items-start justify-center pt-12 z-10">
    <input type="text" class="border-r border-gray">
</div>
```

This just displays a black background with no change to he opacity, so I have tried it within a custom class in case the post processing needs to do some magic:

```
.expanded 
    @apply bg-black bg-opacity-50
```

However, I just get the following error doing it that way:

> `@apply` cannot be used with `.bg-opacity-50` because `.bg-opacity-50` either cannot be found

Running **npm list** displays my tailwinds version as 1.4.1 which should be found to support this feature:

```
+-- tailwindcss@1.4.1
| +-- @fullhuman/postcss-purgecss@2.1.2
| | +-- postcss@7.0.27 deduped
| | `-- purgecss@2.1.2
| |   +-- commander@5.1.0
| |   +-- glob@7.1.6 deduped
| |   +-- postcss@7.0.27 deduped
| |   `-- postcss-selector-parser@6.0.2 deduped
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reduce the opacity of a background you can do the following:

```
<div className="bg-gray-200 hover:opacity-25"></div>
```

There is no bg-opacity-50 option in tailwind. I am using the version 1.3.5 I believe is not too different from your version.  Instead, you can use the following options:

```
opacity-0 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.opacity-25 {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.opacity-50 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.opacity-75 {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.opacity-100 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: This changes the entire diff opacity, backgroud opacity is a new feature: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the background opacity use `::before`. Because you need to find a way to separate the background css. `::before` is a pseudo-element exists in CSS but you cannot see them in the HTML.

```
// you could manipulate it the way u want it
// important part is before:opacity-30
// since I set "absolute" make sure its parent is "relative" position
// content should be "" otherwise it wont show on the page at all
const style={
   wrapper: `before:content-[''] before:absolute before:top-0 before:left-0 before:right-0 before:bottom-0 
             before:bg-[url('imageUrl')] before:bg-cover before:bg-center before:opacity-30`,   
}
```

then in your html:

```
<div class={style.wrapper}>
    // input also should have "relative". you can test it
    <input type="text" class="border-r relative border-gray">
</div>
```